# How to run ruby on rails apps with different versions of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

I have about 3 apps on a Windows Server 2012 and all of them are different versions of rails. So far, I can run locally the app with the latest version of rails, but not the other two, which were deployed from Heroku. I wanted to make changes locally before I push them to Heroku but no luck. Is there any reference to that or is this even possible? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use `sqlite` with Heroku. Heroku requires using 'postgres' as the database

change the gemfile to the following

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And then change your database.yml file to this

```
adapter: postgresql
```

Comment: You know, they are included in the Gemfile. One of the errors that I get from the Heroku app is: C;/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in 'require' cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Comment: Heroku doesn't use `sqlite`, it uses `postgres`

Comment: I see, this is how the Gemfile declares that: `group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
 gem 'thin'
end` is this correct? thanks for the help!

Comment: exactly, since Heroku is production, you place `pg` into the production block

Comment: Now on the database.yml file, when you say `adapter: postgresql` I got development and test with `adapter: postgresql` and production with `adapter: sqlite3` So, do I change in the production to `adapter: postgresql`?

Comment: Yes, but development can still be `adapter: sqlite3`

Comment: Still doesn't work, but thanks - I get the same error about sqlite3.